# Creating an Ad-hoc iOS build to test on other devices using an existing CSR / organization account

Tags: ios, xcode

Okay, I have put a day in this and am super - confused ( hail Android, it's super easy ). A client of mine has an organization developer account on apple, and uses his public-private Key Pair to look after development and deployment of an app on test devices. I am developing another app for him , and can request for his credentials (to generate the public-private Key Pair to sign and create ad - hoc provisioning profile and builds / invite me as a developer of the team on apple , and proceed) . The problem is : I need to issue a CSR ( Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Add Apple ID and request for public - private key ), BUT if I add his account , and generate CSR request to create key-value pair, would that not invalidate the CSR on his Mac and hamper his development? Is there a way out to generate a separate CSR for me using his organization account so that I can create provisioning profiles for an ad - hoc build ? Dang .. this is confusing..

Comment: since xcode 7 launched you can test your build on any iPhone device without provisioning profile and certificate.

Comment: That won't help in creating ad hoc build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that by created a new APP ID specifically for you or your fellow developers and link with the developer profile you create.

Else you can also ask for .p12 file that can be exported from machine keychain from which your client first created CSR certificate from. Just you would require to add to it your mac and download the same profile and certificate from apple's developer portal, finally you can install it on your device.

Comment: does the developer who is assigned as a team member need to purchase apple developer account separately?

Comment: you are getting confused between apple's different accounts and creating a profile for existing account. Which i had replied is when you already have an account. First you should decide you are looking out for development or distribution. If its a development any account can be used apple has a well documented page.

Comment: okay, I created a provisioning profile for distribution, thanks